# Outilne wireframe

Tags: modeling, objects, edit-mode, edges

How can I get a solid with a wireframe outline for all my edges?  I don't want to see the lines if they are on the opposite side of the object.  I want what is in the picture shown but I don't want to have to be selected on it for it to work.  Help!
[image: How can I get a solid with a wireframe outline for all my edges? I don't want to see the lines if they are on the opposite side of the object. I want what is in the picture shown but I don't want to have to be selected on it for it to work. Help!]

Answer (score 1):

Enable Freestyle and render the image (<kbd>F 12</kbd>).

[image]

From the [Blender Manual:](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/freestyle/introduction.html#what-is-freestyle)

> FreeStyle is an edge- and line-based non-photorealistic (NPR) rendering engine. It relies on mesh data and z-depth information to draw lines on selected edge types. Various line styles can be added to produce artistic (“hand drawn”, “painted”, etc.) or technical (hard line) looks.

Make sure thet you set the visibility to **Visible**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wire can be overlayed in solid view object mode.

- Go to Properties panel
- Object tab
- Display
- Check **Wire** and **Draw All Edges**

Without Draw All Edges Blender will hide edges with low angles to make the viewport less cluttered.
[image: wireframe overlay]